# How to access sub-struct variables in Racket (Lisp/Scheme)

Tags: struct, lambda, scheme, lisp, racket

I'm trying to write an AM/PM clock conversion function to a 24 hour clock (military time), but there's a struct and sub-struct that have variables I can't figure out how to pull. Neither 24HourClock-hours or AM/PM-hours is working to pull the hours or minutes variable out of the AM/PM instance of time that goes as the parameter of each of the two versions of the function.

The following two functions are two separate attempts at the same function:

```
(define (AM/PM->24HourClock2 time)
  (cond
   [(isAM? time) (24HourClock (24HourClock-hours 24HourClock-minutes))]
   [else (24HourClock (+ 24HourClock-hours 12) 24HourClock-minutes)]))
```

```
(define (AM/PM->24HourClock time)
  (cond
   [(isAM? time) (24HourClock (AM/PM-hours AM/PM-minutes))]
   [else (24HourClock (+ AM/PM-hours 12) AM/PM-minutes)]))
```

This one attempts to use a lambda function to access the sub-members:

```
(define (AM/PM->24HourClock time)
  (lambda (hr min meridiem)
    (cond
      [(isAM? time) (24HourClock (hr min))]
      [else (24HourClock (+ hr 12) min)]))
```

But here's the output:

[image: output]

Here's the earlier code that makes it reproducible:

```
#lang slideshow

(struct 24HourClock (hours minutes)
  #:transparent
  #:mutable
  #:guard (lambda (hours minutes err_name)
    (if (not (and (>= hours 0) (< hours 24)))
     (error err_name "Hours must be between 0 and 24")
    (if (not (and (>= minutes 0) (< minutes 60)))
     (error err_name "Minutes must be between 0 and 60")
    (values hours minutes)))))

(struct AM/PM 24HourClock (meridiem)
  #:transparent
  #:mutable
  #:guard (lambda (hours minutes meridiem err_name)
            (if (not(and(and(number? hours)(> hours 0)(<= hours 12)(number? minutes))))
                (error err_name "Hours must be between 1 and 12 : 0")
                    (if [not (and(string? meridiem)(or
                         (equal? meridiem "am")
                         (equal? meridiem "AM")
                         (equal? meridiem "pm")
                         (equal? meridiem "PM")))]                    
                    (error err_name "Invalid value for meridiem")
                    (values hours minutes meridiem)))))
       
 (define (isAM? time)
    (or (equal? (AM/PM-meridiem time) "AM")
        (equal? (AM/PM-meridiem time) "am")))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be rather

```
(define (AM/PM->24HourClock2 time)
  (cond
   [(isAM? time) (24HourClock (AM/PM-hours time) (AM/PM-minutes time))]
   [else (24HourClock (+ (AM/PM-hours time) 12) (AM/PM-minutes time))]))

(define (AM/PM->24HourClock time)
  (let ((hr (AM/PM-hours time))
        (min (AM/PM-minutes time))
        (mer (AM/PM-meridiem time)))
    (cond
      [(isAM? time) (24HourClock hr min)]
      [else (24HourClock (+ hr 12) min)])))
```

But since `AM/PM-hours` and `AM/PM-minutes` are not defined when defining like you did here with `24HourClock` as super class, you have to write:

```
(define (AM/PM->24HourClock2 time)
  (cond
   [(isAM? time) (24HourClock (24HourClock-hours time) (24HourClock-minutes time))]
   [else (24HourClock (+ (24HourClock-hours time) 12) (24HourClock-minutes time))]))

(define (AM/PM->24HourClock time)
  (let ((hr (24HourClock-hours time))
        (min (24HourClock-minutes time))
        (mer (AM/PM-meridiem time)))
    (cond
      [(isAM? time) (24HourClock hr min)]
      [else (24HourClock (+ hr 12) min)])))
```

Your problem is that you think `struct-slot` is itself the value of slot in struct. But it isn't. It is just the getter function for the `slot` in `struct`. Therefore, you have to do `(struct-slot instance)` to get the value of `slot` in the `instance` which is of the type `struct`.

If you want `AM/PM->24HourClock`, then `time` is of the type `AM/PM`.

Comment: oh.. wait but then hows come the above AM/PM-hours and AM/PM-minutes don't work? Is it due to sub-scope?

Comment: No, they are functions. You have to apply this function on the `time`: `(AM/PM-hours time)`. `(AM/PM-minutes time)`.

Comment: I think you think in terms of OOP languages. Somehow you think `AM/PM-hours` is like `AM/PM.hours` - I think you think `-` is like the dot operator or such ... it isn't.

Comment: `struct-slot` are getter functions which you have to apply on objects/structs of that type `struct` to get the values of those instances of those types/structures.

Comment: If you define a struct with its slots, then macros automatically define the getter functions `struct-slot` for each of the lots automatically. In addition, also some predicate function like `struct?` gets defined under the hood. So you get the function `(AM/PM? time)` working right after definition of the struct `AM/PM`. Such stuff is possible through the metaprogramming abilities of lisps (macros).

Comment: it's still saying there's an unbound identifier for AM/PM-hours and the other getters, ```AM/PM-hours: unbound identifier in: AM/PM-hours```

Comment: can you show the code and the error?

Comment: Why your code has `#lang slideshow` at top instead of `#lang racket`?

Comment: this code can use either slideshow or racket, but normally if I'm using shapes I'd use slideshow, I've post in an answer the code and error because it's too much to put in a comment, only the very end is the part that's not working

Comment: ah I see: the problem is that you use 24HoursClock in the struct definition of AM/PM - indeed if you define AM/PM like this, you can give hours and minutes as argument to AM/PM but the getter functions `AM/PM-hours` and `AM/PM-minutes` are not defined. One has to use `24HourClock-hours` and `24HourClock-minutes` instead.

Comment: Now I improved the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is all code put together, it's the same as your response and what was shown:

```
#lang slideshow

(struct 24HourClock (hours minutes) #:transparent #:mutable
  #:guard (lambda (hours minutes err_name)
    (if (not (and (>= hours 0) (< hours 24)))
     (error err_name "Hours must be between 0 and 24")
    (if (not (and (>= minutes 0) (< minutes 60)))
     (error err_name "Minutes must be between 0 and 60")
    (values hours minutes)))))

(struct AM/PM 24HourClock (meridiem) #:transparent #:mutable
  #:guard (lambda (hours minutes meridiem err_name)
            (if (not(and(and(number? hours)(> hours 0)(<= hours 12)(number? minutes))))
                (error err_name "Hours must be between 1 and 12 : 0")
                    (if [not (and(string? meridiem)(or
                         (equal? meridiem "am")
                         (equal? meridiem "AM")
                         (equal? meridiem "pm")
                         (equal? meridiem "PM")))]                    
                    (error err_name "Invalid value for meridiem")
                    (values hours minutes meridiem)))))
         
 (define (isAM? time)
    (or (equal? (AM/PM-meridiem time) "AM")
        (equal? (AM/PM-meridiem time) "am")))

(define (AM/PM->24HourClock time)
  (let ((hr (AM/PM-hours time))
        (min (AM/PM-minutes time))
    (cond
      [(isAM? time) (24HourClock hr min)]
      [else (24HourClock (+ hr 12) min)])))
```

[image: error]

Here's what I use for test cases:

```
;=======================
;    Test Cases
;=======================

; (24HourClock 0 20)
; (24HourClock 24 20)
; (24HourClock 11 60)
; (AM/PM 0 20 "AM")
; (AM/PM 1 20 "Am")
; (AM/PM 2 20 "am")
; (is-AM? 2 20 "am")

; (AM/PM->24HourClock (AM/PM 0 10 "AM"))
; (AM/PM->24HourClock (AM/PM 12 10 "am"))
```